# Heroku JawsDB Leopard Shared plan is throwing ulimit error when Django runs migrations

Tags: mysql, django, heroku

In Heroku we have a hosted Django app with provisioned MySQL database from JawsDB (Leopard Shared plan). 
The problem occurs on while running Django migrate command as part of Heroku release cycle. We get this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1041, "Out of memory; check if
>   mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you
>   may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can
>   add more swap space")

We pinpointed that it fails on the ALTER TABLE that adds a new foreign key column.

Any idea what can we do from here or what can we do as a workaround?